# Docker MySql Operation Not Permitted

Tags: mysql, docker

I have my docker compose as follows but am getting an operation not permitted mbind issue. It's been awhile but as far as I remember it was seeding with the db/init before. I have 2 sql files in there that I exported from a seeded db in the past via MySQL Workbench.

```
db_1             | 2022-05-17T03:52:16.766919Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1             | mbind: Operation not permitted
```

```yaml
  db:
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=investing
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=777
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes: 
      - "./db/init:/tmp/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very curious thing but apparently I now needed to add security options to docker compose. I haven't upgraded docker but I did upgrade my Linux OS. I can't think of any other major system changes to prompt the issue.

```yaml
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```

```yaml
  db:
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=investing
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=777
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: on-failure
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    volumes: 
      - "./db/init:/tmp/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

My db/init is still no longer seeding but that may be out of the scope of this question.